# Is there any way to skip particular words from translation in 'GoogleTranslate()' function in spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-translate, google-sheets-formula, google-translation-api

I am using `GoogleTranslate()` with Sheets to translate some contents into different languages. In those contents, we have some placeholders that do not need to translate. E.g.:

```
This is a Sample Text added by `{__NAME__}` on `{__DATE__}`
```

I do not need to translate placeholders like `{__NAME__}`  and `{__DATE__}`.

How can I skip those words from the translation process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(QUERY(
 REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, " ")), "\{.*\}", "♦"),, 999^99), "en", "es"), " ")),
 {REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, " ")), "\{.*\}", "♦"), TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, " "))}, 2, 0),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(GOOGLETRANSLATE(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, " ")), "\{.*\}", "♦"),,999), "en", "es"), " "))),,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: holly cow, so surprised that magician from google haven't a simple excluding pattern.

Comment: This fails in translating to Japanese, Hebrew, and Chinese.

Input: 
I'm {__%age%__} years old
output in Japanese
私は♦歳です


Also doesn't work if there is a number on the input

Answer (score 2):

Finally find a way, as it seems logical that gtranslate don't translate email adress you can easily protect words with email pattern:

exemple, translating the following sentence from en to ru:
"I need %amount% of cherry"

Original translate from en to ru using: `=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A3,"en", "ru")`

**"Мне нужно% Сумма% вишни"**

Step1: replacing %amount% by skip@skip.amount.skip.com :

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(REGEXREPLACE(A3, "%(.*?)%", "skip@skip.$1.skip.com"),"en", "ru")
```

**Мне нужно skip@skip.amount.skip.com вишни**

Step2 : replacing back skip@skip.amount.skip.com with %amount%,

```
=REGEXREPLACE(GOOGLETRANSLATE(REGEXREPLACE(A5, "%(.*?)%", "skip@skip.$1.skip.com"),"en", "tr"), "(?i)skip@\s*skip.(.*?).skip.com", "%$1%")
```

**Мне нужно %amount% вишни**

Comment: If it's a single word this fails by preparing the word multiple times